# What's the current status of Esperanto movement in North Korea?

Tags: movado

Is there an active Esperanto movement in North Korea today?

[According to Vikipedio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto-movado_en_Nord-Koreio), a North Korean Esperanto Association was founded in 1959 and published a dictionary. But there are no more information about it after.

From the same page in Vikipedio, the KFA used to have an Esperanto page as late as 2005, but not anymore it seems.

In [a book about North Korea](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=BCRMrY9Zx1IC&lpg=PA89&ots=WhLmOLH3UD&dq=esperanto%20movement%20in%20north%20korea&pg=PA89#v=onepage&q&f=false), I read that there was an Esperanto movement there:

[image]

All this makes me very interested in knowing:

- Is the movement there still active today? How many members do they have?
- Do they attend the UEA? Or have any external relationships?
- How did their association develop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Vikipedia* article you linked to appears to be a reposting of an article in *Libera Folio*. Both versions of the article contain the following line:

> La sola konata ligo inter Esperanto kaj Norda Koreio dum la lastaj jaroj estis Asocio por Amikeco kun Koreujo, KFA, fondita en la jaro 2000.

The web site in question appears to have been taken down. (The link from the LF article does not work.) Using the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20060822043440/http://www.korea-dpr.com:80/users/esperanto/kfa.html) I verified that the page was still working in 2007 and was written in decent, but not perfect, Esperanto. It's difficult to get a sense of who wrote it or what their contact with the outside world was.

In 2005 Monato published an [Article by Ulrich Lins](http://www.monato.net/2005/008536.php) who had traveled to North Korea. The last line in the article seems to be an answer to your questions:

> Sed de preskaŭ 40 jaroj mankas ĉia informo pri Esperanto-movado en Norda Koreio.

If someone like Ulrich Lins says there's no information about Esperantists in North Korea, I'm inclined to believe him. [Certainly](https://www.quora.com/Are-North-Koreans-allowed-to-travel-outside-their-country-If-not-why) no North Korean Esperantist has been able to travel to a foreign Esperanto meeting in decades.

Comment: It is interesting (but not wholly unexpected) that Esperantists always seem to end up on the wrong side of authoritarian regimes!

Comment: @OliverMason well, china promoted esperanto.... and UK has been to cuba twice...

Comment: I sent a mail to the KFA esperanto address and received an error message, looks like it no longer functions.

Comment: @Zuoanqh : "The web site in question appears to have been taken down. (The link from the LF article does not work.) Using the Wayback Machine I verified that the page was still working in 2007" --- the word "wayback" is hot-linked to a cached version of the KFA web page.

Comment: @TomasoAlexander oh yeah, i understand, but i thought the mail might still be functioning. eh. really leaves me wondering, if there are esperantists 10 years ago, what happened between those times?

Comment: I'm more curious about how that web page got put up in the first place. From 2000 possibly as late as 2007... 50 years after the end of the Korean war, there were people in North Korea who could write decent Esperanto. Who were they practicing with? How could they get young people to learn the language without the promise of actually communicating with people from other cultures? How old were these people in 2000? At this point they're almost 20 years older, for sure.

Comment: Sorry - I misread your comment - email vs website. Mia kulpo.